# I am trying to install Ubuntu in virualbox and it keeps crashing. Please help

Tags: 14.04, system-installation, virtualbox, crash

This is  screenshot of my settings in virtual box:

[image]

and this is a screenshot of the crash:

[image]

This happens happens right after I select install Ubuntu

Comment: Have you already tried to increase video memory and enable 3D acceleration in display settings?

Comment: Might be worth a try to remove the tick from 'Extended Features : Enable PAE/NX'. This is under System --> Processor.

Comment: As well if you right click on the failing VM in the main Virtual Box window select 'Show Log' and pastebin this log...

Comment: Disabling PAE/NX gave me an error saying that I need PAE. This is the log http://pastebin.com/5MC7qNCE

Comment: I had an issue once trying to install it on a vm. It ended up being permissions on the laptop I was on and that until settee gs were changed in the BIOS, all I coyld do was install a 32 bit version. I haf a look at the screen shot bit cannot see which verion yoy are trying to install.

Comment: I'm trying to install 14.04. That might be the problem though. I had a permissions issue with this laptop when I first upgraded to window 10 and I had to reinstall it so that I could save any files. How did you fix that?